# C# 'Basics.Product' does not contain a definition for 'ProductGroup'

Tags: c#, string, class

So, I'm having some practices for classes and I've been easily stuck with classes for a week or so. I don't know how to refer from one class to another classes, but my assignment requires me to do that.

I've translated my code in english.

```
    using System;
    namespace Basics
    {
        // Sinun koodi tulee tähän
        public class Product
            {
                string name;
                decimal price;

                public Product(string name, object ProductGroup, decimal price)
                {
                    this.Price = price;
                    this.Name = name;
                }

                public Product(string name, object ProductGroup)
                {
                    this.Name = name;
                }

                public decimal Price
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return price;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        price = value;
                    }
                }

                private string Name
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return name;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        name = value;
                    }
                }



                public string Summary
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return this.Name + this.ProductGroup + this.Price;
                    }
                }
            }

        public class ProductGroup
        {
                string name;

                public string Name
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return name;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        name = value;
                    }
                }


                public ProductGroup(string name)
                {
                    this.Name = name;
                }
        }


        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {


                Product[] purchases = new Product[2];
                ProductGroup applianceGroup = new ProductGroup("Appliances");
                purchases[0] = new Product("Coffeemaker", applianceGroup, 49.90M);
                purchases[1] = new Product("Microwave", applianceGroup);
                purchases[1].Price = 99.90M;
                decimal sum = 0;
                foreach (Product t in purchases)
                {
                    sum += t.Price;
                    Console.WriteLine(t.Summary);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Totals {0:f2}", sum);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }     
        }
    }
```

The line which gives me problems is `return this.Name + this.ProductGroup + this.Price;`

Returns me the error `'Basics.Product' does not contain a definition for 'ProductGroup' and no extension method 'ProductGroup' accepting a first argument of type 'Basics.Product' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (ADVICE) Make for each class a seperate *.cs file and make sure they have the same namespace. edited on @Chris suggestion ^^

Comment: @Sebastian: while that may be good advice for neat code you should clarify that this is what you are suggesting and not a fix to the problem (since that won't help).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have no property on `Product` called `ProductGroup` so it doesn't know what you are referring to. You will want to create a new property of type `ProductGroup` that can be called ProductGroup as well.

```
public ProductGroup ProductGroup {get; set;}
```

This is using [c# auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb384054.aspx) available from c#3 onwards. You can do this with a backing field as you have done other as well though.

Then  you would change your constructor to save this variable (which you are already passing in):

```
public Product(string name, ProductGroup productGroup)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.ProductGroup = productGroup;
}
```

Note that I have changed the type of the parameter to the constructor as well as adding the assignment. Obviously update your other constructor in the same way and then it should work as you would hope.

Comment: Did that, now I'm getting `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Basics.ProductGroup'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Have you changed the types of the parameters to the constructor? You shouldn't really have `object` anywhere in your code (you would almost always want to specify a more specific type as I did in my updated constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Further to Chris's answer, I think it might help giving the property a different name than its type. When starting out it can prevent possible confusion. Eg:

```
public Product(string name, ProductGroup group)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Group = group;
}

public ProductGroup Group {get; set;}
```

Comment: Further asking, how can I write text into the field group? Using `string group;` returns me with `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Basics.ProductGroup'`